# Reading numerical values from two separate images at once for calculation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-tesseract

So, I have a very basic knowledge of python and it's a bit difficult for me to crack.

My goal is to calculate something based on the values collected from two images, say x1 from image1 and x2 from image2, and I want to calculate (x1 * x2). I am using pytessaract library to get the x1 and x2 values from the images. However, to calculate x1 and x2, I need to read image1 and image2 simultaneously. So, I can read x1 and x2 separately from image1 and image2, but when it comes to calculating (x1 * x2) or combining the values, I am lost :(

Can somebody help me with how to do that? Or any references would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider showing whatever small code you already have. For example normally it's "Pythonic" to directly loop over values, but if you want to process multiple images, you are probably better off with looping over coordinates. But without seeing what you have it's not possible to tell what kind of actual issue you are facing, only guesses remain.

Comment: The message is right. `dict2 = copy.deepcopy(self.structures_dict2)` is inside an `if`, so it either happens or not. While `all_values2 = list(nested_dict_values_iterator(dict2))` always runs.